# redirect url ends with .php page to custom 404 page using htaccess caused the custom 404 page broke

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /exception/404.php
//if url ends with .php/ , show custom 404 page
RewriteRule .php/$ - [R=404,L]
//this line caused the custom 404 page broken
RewriteRule .php$ - [R=404,L]
```

before I added line 4:
speedcubing.top/index.php

(show the index page)

speedcubing.top/index.php/

(show custom 404 page)

after I added line 4:
speedcubing.top/index.php
speedcubing.top/index.php/

they both showing:

Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ErrorDocument` directive and `RewriteRule` directive are from different Apache modules that run at different times. Hence setting `R=404` doesn't cause Apache to invoke `ErrorDocument` handler and it ends up showing default `404` Apache handler.

You should add this line in your `/exception/404.php` to set a custom http response code:

```php
<?php
http_response_code(404);
// rest of the code
?>
```

And have your .htaccess code like this:

```bash
ErrorDocument 404 /exception/404.php

RewriteEngine On

# if url ends with .php or .php/, show custom 404 page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exception/404\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.php/?$ exception/404.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: @speedcubing: Did this work out?

Comment: I'm having internal server error now. (speedcubing.top/index.php)

Comment: try my updated code now